# Emit event in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Как правильно решить эту проблему

Сomponent emitted event "cancel" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onCancel" prop

Тут я принял

```
@cancel="isRighted = false"
```

Тут я отправил

```
@click="$emit('close')"
```

Comment: Замените `@cancel="isRighted = false"` на `@close="isRighted = false"`.

Comment: Component emitted event "close" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onClose" prop.

Comment: Попробуй переименовать пропсу на `onClose`

Comment: получается у меня идёт пропса через три компонента @handle-drow="getClose"
@handle-cancel="handleDrow"
@is-righted="handleCancel"
handleClose() {
  this.$emit('is-righted', false);
},

Comment: Обновите вопрос пожалуйста, добавьте туда этот код.